# create dynamic mulit-select dual listbox in jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, multi-select, dropdownbox, html-datalist

I am using this [documentation](https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) for multi-select datalist, actually, I am trying to make this datalist dynamically. I want to append and remove the `<option>` in `#duallist` on the `#option_name` `change()` event.
I am able to append the option but when I click the single option tag then all option tags move to another box.
I am not able to remove / empty and reset the datalist.
as much I understand the documentation I do but it not worked.

I am appending the option which comes in JSON format through my backed code.

this is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twt2shiv/13huL7v5/11/) Please help me How to make my datalist dynamically.

```
$('select#duallist').bootstrapDualListbox();

$("select#option_name").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $('select#duallist').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true); //remove all the previous data
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./url.php",
    data: {
      value: value,
      type: "fetch_data"
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      var len = response.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var id = response[i]['id'];
        var data = response[i]['data'];

        $("select#duallist").append("<option value='" + id + "'>" + data + "</option>");
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, your code almost work just add `$('select#duallist').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);` after `for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {..}` .

Comment: how to I empty and reset `#duallist`

Comment: use `$('select#duallist').html("")` before appending new options .

Comment: no, it is not working, previous options did not remove when the change  event `#option_name`. even filter box not resets.

Comment: are you seeing that behaviour [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ogfcre41/) as well ?

Comment: how we choose and select auto selected value?

Comment: That's not related to this post you can ask another question for same .

Comment: please help me last time

Comment: Sorry i am not sure if i know about that :) That's the reason i told to ask another question.